# What App Pool configuration do you recommend for this?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, performance

I have a website which does convertion of pdfs to word docs. My server is **8GB** Quad-Core Opteron.

A conversion can take between 1 seconds for a small pdf file (eg 35kb) to 60 seconds (for pdf files of 5Mb).

I have about 10 requests for conversions per minute with medium files size of pdf being about 1-2 Mb.

I know that for web apps which depends on CPU high usage it's better to have multiple **worker processes** so I put 5 being maximum. (so a user does not have to wait for others to finish their conversion but can have a process opened for it). I also put **PrivateMemoryLimit** being about 1GB. Also **Request Limit** is 500 (to have it recycled from time to time).

Well, sometimes the CPU goes *90-100%* or memory goes *70-90%*.

Do you have any better configuration proposals for such cases?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or something else. That kinda matters a bit.

Comment: yes, it is ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc745955.aspx) which lists in table form the default settings for IIS7 and the settings the Microsoft.com team uses on their servers.  This might give you enough to get started with and make a decision on.  They hardly ever recycle their application pools because they need the resources up and running.

Either way, this question doesn't work well for ServerFault because each admin will have their own opinion on how best to configure a server.  There is no wrong answer a lot of the time.  You application is performing CPU and Memory intensive functions in the first place so its not all that surprising the amount of memory and CPU usage you are seeing.  Instead of worrying about the server you may want to investigate your code to make sure you are disposing of objects properly and potentially forcing garbage collection to clear out resources as well.

Comment: +1 for "investigate your code."  That's what's doing all the heavy lifting, so a small optimization there will have a bigger impact than an optimization of similar scale on an OS-level or server-level.  Always hit the low hanging fruit first.